# Why does my MSYS2/MinGW64 setup link SDL2 without a -l directive, but not SDL2_ttf?

Tags: codeblocks, sdl-2, mingw-w64, msys2

I have MSYS2 and MinGW64 installed.  I also have Code::Blocks installed and have pointed it's toolchain configuration to the executables in MinGW64's bin. To keep things clean, I have only installed libraries using pacman from the MinGW64 shell.

```
$ pacman -Sl | grep SDL2
mingw32 mingw-w64-i686-SDL2 2.0.9-1
mingw32 mingw-w64-i686-SDL2_gfx 1.0.4-1
mingw32 mingw-w64-i686-SDL2_image 2.0.4-1
mingw32 mingw-w64-i686-SDL2_mixer 2.0.4-1
mingw32 mingw-w64-i686-SDL2_net 2.0.1-1
mingw32 mingw-w64-i686-SDL2_ttf 2.0.14-1
mingw64 mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2 2.0.9-1 [installed]
mingw64 mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_gfx 1.0.4-1 [installed]
mingw64 mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_image 2.0.4-1 [installed]
mingw64 mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_mixer 2.0.4-1 [installed]
mingw64 mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_net 2.0.1-1 [installed]
mingw64 mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_ttf 2.0.14-1 [installed]
```

Using Code::Blocks, I can compile and link a sample that initializes SDL2, pops a window, and exits on an SDL_Quit event.  The sample project has NO additional compiler or linker configuration.  In fact, Code::Blocks global settings do not configure search directories, either.  I suppose GCC has INCLUDE and LIB already set in its default environment.

The problem occurs when I try to use SDL2_ttf.  I can include it, and Code::Blocks finds it well-enough to offer some code completion.  But builds fail on "Undefined reference to TTF_Init".

```
-------------- Build: Debug in TV Tennis (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -LD:\msys64\mingw64\lib -o "bin\Debug\TV Tennis.exe" obj\Debug\main.o   -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2.dll -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -ldxguid
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `SDL_main':
H:/Datacenter/Source/TVTennis/C++/TV Tennis/main.cpp:45: undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
H:/Datacenter/Source/TVTennis/C++/TV Tennis/main.cpp:59: undefined reference to `TTF_OpenFont'
H:/Datacenter/Source/TVTennis/C++/TV Tennis/main.cpp:109: undefined reference to `TTF_CloseFont'
H:/Datacenter/Source/TVTennis/C++/TV Tennis/main.cpp:110: undefined reference to `TTF_Quit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

If I add "-lSDL2_ttf" to the project's linker options, the problem goes away.

My question is, why do I get that automatic linking magic for SDL2, but not for SDL2_ttf?

Comment: Can you show us the build log from CB?

Comment: Added failed build log.

Comment: You added the contents of `Build messages` tab, but there is also `Build log` tab.

Comment: Build log, for real this time =).

Comment: So you say *"NO additional compiler or linker configuration"*, but I'm seein' `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2.dll` in there. Looks like those actually are in your linker settings, and you're looking at the wrong settings.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Thank you for being insistent about my posting the build log.  It showed me the actual command line being used to compile and link.  Seeing those linker directives there made me think long and hard about where they came from.  Code::Blocks does a very bad thing.  It adds link libraries via its proprietary project file (*.cbp) that are not visible anywhere in the global or project configuration pages of the application.  But I opened up the cbp file and sure enough...

Answer (score 1):

I found out how SDL2 was "magically" linked in without any visible configuration or explicit directive.

When I created the Code::Blocks project, I specified it as an SDL2 project.  Code::Blocks then adds a bunch of libraries to the project by default via the project's *.cbp file (Code::Blocks Project).

```
<Compiler>
    <Add option="-Wall" />
    <Add directory="D:/msys64/mingw64/include" />
</Compiler>
<Linker>
    <Add library="mingw32" />
    <Add library="SDL2main" />
    <Add library="SDL2.dll" />
    <Add library="user32" />
    <Add library="gdi32" />
    <Add library="winmm" />
    <Add library="dxguid" />
    <Add directory="D:/msys64/mingw64/lib" />
</Linker>
<ExtraCommands>
    <Add after="XCOPY $(#sdl2)\bin\*.dll $(TARGET_OUTPUT_DIR) /D /Y" />
</ExtraCommands>
```

Honestly, this is why I hate starting with project templates; especially when I am new to a language, IDE, or library.  And in this case, I am new to all three.

Comment: Are you sure those don't show up in project settings? In `Project build options` there is a set of settings for the entire project (which can be opened by clicking on the project name on the left), and a few separate sets of settings for each specific 'target' (which can be opened by clicking on a target name on the left, e.g. on 'release' or 'debug'); you need to check both.

Comment: I've heard it said, "only a fool is sure".  I don't know Code::Blocks very well.  But when I right-click the project in the explorer, click "Build options", and then nav to the "Linker settings", there is nothing there.  Then, from the menu bar, "Settings", "Compiler...", "Linker settings" tab, there is nothing there.  Still, as I pasted, the project has those linker options hidden away in that project file.